# Identification of an ARX model with both linear equality constraints and stability

Tags: matlab, optimization, signal-processing, linear-regression, system-identification

From input and output data I have to identify with least squares an ARX model

> y(n) = -a1 y(n-1) -....- aN y(n-N)  + b1 x(n-1)+...+bM x(n-M)

that has to be stable (all its poles are inside the unit circle) and at the same time the parameters

> a1,...,aN, b1,...,bM

have to satisfy some linear equality constraints.
For example I need a static gain equal to 1, this means

> -a1-a2...-aN+b1+b2...+bM =1

In matrix form I can write the constraint as:

> Theta = [a1 a2 ... aN b1 b2 ... bM]';
>
> Aeq = [-ones(1,N) ones(1,M)];
>
> beq = 1;
>
> Aeq*theta=beq;

With the below Matlab function `arx_stable` I can identify the stable `ARX` using the Matlab function 'ARX' setting the parameter `'Focus' ='stability'` (but without the equality linear constraints)

With the below function `arx_constr` I can identify the `ARX` with the linear equality constraints Aeq beq (but without the stability)

How can I get both stability and respect of the constraints???
Thanks,

Simone

```
function theta = arx_stable(N,M,t,input_data,output_data)
% input_data and output_data are column vectors
% t is the time vector
% data structure generation:
Ts = t(2)-t(1); % it is the sampling time
data = iddata(output_data,input_data,Ts);
n_k=0; % it is the Input-output delay
ARX_model = arx(data,[N M n_k]  , 'Focus','stability');  
% 'Focus','stability' in this way the identified ARX is stable
a=ARX_model.a;
a=a(2:end); % I remove the first a0=1
b=ARX_model.b;
theta=[a b];
end

function theta = arx_constr(N,M,t,input_data,output_data,Aeq,beq)
% input_data and ouput_data are row vectors
% t is the time vector
% X and y construction:
n_order=max([N M]);
X=[];  % X is the regression matrix
for nn = n_order+1:length(input_data)
    X(nn,:)=[-output_data((nn-1):-1:(nn-N)) input_data((nn-1):-1:(nn-M))];
end
X=X((n_order+1):end,:); % it cancels the first n_order rows that are full of zeros
y=output_data(n_order+1:end)' ;   %  y is a column vector
options_lsqlin=optimset('Algorithm','active-set','LargeScale','off');   
% this set is necessary to use equality constraints
theta=lsqlin(X,y,[],[],Aeq,beq,[],[],[],options_lsqlin);
end
```

Comment: Is this question alive??

Comment: Yes the question is still alive

Comment: Ok, Lets solve this issue once and for all. Lets talk tomorrow.... It is a bit late here...